# Receiving an empty array when requesting list items from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph to access the items of a SharePoint List with fetch requests on a JS application.

When I make the following request:

```
export const getList = access_token => {
  const token = "Bearer " + access_token;

  const url = `${apiUrl}/${siteId}/lists/${listId}`;

  return fetch(url, {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      Authorization: token,
      Accept: "application/json;odata.metadata=none"
    }
  }).then(res => res.json());
};
```

What I get is a valid JSON response with details about the list in question.

However, when I use this request:

```
export const getItems = access_token => {
  const url = `${apiUrl}/${siteId}/lists/${listId}/items`;
  const token = "Bearer " + access_token;

  return fetch(url, {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      Authorization: token,
      Accept: "application/json;odata.metadata=none"
    }
  }).then(res => res.json());
};
```

which I think is supposed to return the items contained in that list, I get a response with an empty array, although the list is not empty.

I probably should add that I'm using the following URL to get the access token:

```
const tokenUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${siteURL}/oauth2/v2.0/token`
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Adding the responses received when making the requests

When getting information of a list with the URL:

```
const url = `${apiUrl}/${siteId}/lists/${listId}`;
```

the response is the following object:

```
{
    createdBy: {user: {…}}
    createdDateTime: "2018-09-13T04:01:11Z"
    description: ""
    displayName: "Pessoa"
    eTag ""70c738b2-d857-4431-a079-bcc0c60efbe4,16""
    id: "70c738b2-d857-4431-a079-bcc0c60efbe4"
    lastModifiedDateTime: "2018-09-13T04:08:47Z"
    list: {contentTypesEnabled: false, hidden: false, template: "genericList"}
    name: "Pessoa"
    parentReference: {}
    webUrl: "https://incubadorahabits.sharepoint.com/sites/PlataformaTecnologica/Lists/Pessoa"
}
```

When trying to get the list items with the URL:

```
const url = `${apiUrl}/${siteId}/lists/${listId}/items`;
```

the response is:

```
{
    value: []
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the siteID in your SharePoint site is correct? If so, could you please provide the response in the console?

Comment: The siteID is correct. I edited to include the responses. You can see that when I make a request for the list details, the response is as expected, so it is indeed the right siteID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Empty* results for `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items endpoint` usually means that required permissions are missing. 
To query SharePoint list items,  depending on the list type the following permission scope needs to be specified:

- for SharePoint **List**: `Sites.Read.All` or `Sites.ReadWrite.All`
- for SharePoint **Library**: `Files.Read.All` or `Files.ReadWrite.All`