# How do you get SharePoint List Items using the c# sdk for the GraphAPI?

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to pull all the items in a SharePoint list using the Graph API.
I can successfully get the list details using:
`_graphClient.Sites["{siteId}"].Lists["{listId}"].Request().GetAsync();`

However, as soon as a try to get the list items either using `[...].Items.[...]` or `[...].Request(new List<Option>{ new QueryOption("$expand", "items") }).[...]`, the items array comes back as an empty list.

The API already has the 'Sites.Read.All' permission.

What is missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving an empty array when requesting list items from Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879691/receiving-an-empty-array-when-requesting-list-items-from-microsoft-graph-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the items of a SharePoint list using the following code:

```
 var items = await graphClient
      .Sites["mytenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:"]
      .Lists["test"]
      .Items.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: @Darrell Miller thanks for this! Would be really helpful if the sdk docs mentioned that site and list urls could be used instead of ids https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: It is also possible to add a QueryOptions on `Items.Request(new List<Microsoft.Graph.QueryOption>(){ new ("expand", "fields") })`

Comment: how do you get the name "test"? for me it's like {site}/ABCDEF123/list name.aspx, i don't know what to do